# Disk partitioning ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning

I am planning to install Ubuntu 12.10 along with windows.
I would like to know how to partition the drive so that I can access all my data
in windows and keep one separate 20 GB for Ubuntu...

Thank You..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommend you to set your Windows pagefile to a fixed size (min = max) and then reduce the size of Windows partition (C:) as much as you can (or about 10 GB larger that the present used space) **using the Disk management Tool in Windows**. Otherwise you may have problems with booting Windows via Grub bootloader which will be installed with Ubuntu.

Second, you can then boot your Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB in "try without installing" mode and start **GParted Partition Editor** there to make partitions before Ubuntu installation (although this is performed at the beginning of the installation, I find it better doing this in advance). At his stage, considering that you can have **maximun 4 Primary Partitions** in a disk, you might need to create an **Extended Partition** in which you can have as many Logical Partitions as you might need. A **Data partition** to use jointly with Windows may be in NTFS format (with an appropriate entry in Ubuntu system file **/etc/fstab**), about 20GB Ubuntu partition and about 4GB swap partition, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gparted` available in ubuntu live. Try to resize a partition. NTFS partitions are also recognized in Ubuntu, so you can keep your data on those kinds of partitions.

Comment: Resizing the Windows partition using **GParted** sometimes (often?) renders Windows unbootable, which can be solved using **Windows Recovery Disk**. Nevertheless, this course of action may also be preferred to make a huge amount of free space which Windows egoistically refuses to surrender for use in another partition.